# obtaining and Storing a Struct 2D array or matrix from a void function

Tags: c, matrix

I obtain a 2x2 matrix from a NxM matrix. after this I need to find its determinant and hence the inverse, however the 2x2 matrix just seems to be deleted all together outside the for loop instead of being saved as a variable in the `struct matrix` where I intend for it to be stored. I do not know what I am doing wrong, as I am a beginner. the new 2x2 matrix `m2` does not seem to display anything. Please note that the matrix elements have been obtained from a file.

```
void matrixDeterminant(struct Matrix mat, struct Matrix *m2)
{
  int mrow = 0;    
  int mcol = 0;    

  /********************************************************/
  // NEW EDIT

  (*m2).rows = 2;
  (*m2).cols = 2;


  printf("Finding determinant\n");

  printf("Enter row to start the 2x2 matrix:\n");
  scanf("%d", &mrow);

  printf("Enter column to start the 2x2 matrix:\n");
  scanf("%d", &mcol);

  //deducing a new matrix 
  
  for(int i = mrow; i <= mrow+1; i++)
  {
    printf("Row %d:  ", i-2);
    for(int j = mcol; j <= mcol+1; j++)
    { 
      // defining a new 2x2 matrix 
      (*m2).Matrix[i][j] = (mat).Matrix[i-1][j-1];
      printf("\t%.2f",(*m2).Matrix[i][j]);
    
    }
    printf("\n");
   }
   
}


the Output:
Enter one character name of the matrix, e.g, A, B etc:  
A
Enter # rows of matrix (<10):
5
Enter # columns of matrix (<10):
5
Matrix A: 
The matrix is: 
Row 1:      2.00    4.00    2.00    4.00    1.00
Row 2:      2.00    -5.00   1.00    10.00   10.00
Row 3:      -7.00   10.00   10.00   0.00    6.00
Row 4:      -8.00   -2.00   9.00    6.00    10.00
Row 5:      3.00    -10.00  7.00    9.00    4.00
Finding determinant now!
Enter a row where to start the 2x2 matrix:
3
Enter a column where to start the 2x2 matrix:
3
Row 1:      10.00   0.00
Row 2:      9.00    6.00
The matrix is:
```

Comment: Please don't edit the question to "correct bugs" that were pointed out to you in answers. That makes the whole post nonsense for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set `rows` and `cols` for the `m2` matrix... so it wont be displayed.

Just assign them somewhere inside the `matrixDeterminant` function:

```
/*...*/

(*m2).rows = n;
(*m2).cols = n;

/*...*/
```

## Update

In the `matrixDeterminant` function, you are using 2 indexes (the values `i` and `j`) in a nested `for` **to read** a 2x2 matrix **from the matrix `mat`**. The problem is you are using *the same indexes* **to write** them **to the `m2` matrix** (which incorrectly seems to be OK because you can print the values using the same erroneous indexes), causing an overflow since the data is written outside of the matrix boundaries.

I strongly suggest you to rewrite the for to make it *far more readable*, but this not *strictly* necessary, since you *can* (even when you shouldn't) fix the problem by just adding 2 integers and using/incrementing them inside the for:

```
int y = 0;
for(int i = row; i <= row+1; i++)
{
    int x = 0;
    printf("Row %d:  ", i-2);
    for(int j = col; j <= col+1; j++)
    { 
      // defining a new 2x2 matrix 
      (*m2).Matrix[y][x] = (mat).Matrix[i-1][j-1];
      printf("\t%.2f",(*m2).Matrix[y][x]);
      x++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    y++;
}
```

**I** prefer the fix written bellow:

```
/*2x2 sub-matrix*/
void matrixDeterminant(struct matrix mat, struct matrix *m2)
{
  int baseRow = 0;
  int baseCol = 0;
  printf("Finding determinant now!\n");
  printf("Enter a row where to start the 2x2 matrix:\n");
  scanf("%d", &baseRow);
  printf("Enter a column where to start the 2x2 matrix:\n");
  scanf("%d", &baseCol);
  
  /* 
  Since the input is expected to be given in a "human readable"  format,
  I decrease both 'baseRow' and 'baseCol' so they can be in "program natural" format.
  */
  baseRow--;
  baseCol--;

  (*m2).rows = 2;
  (*m2).cols = 2;
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    printf("Row %d:  ", i+1);
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    { 
      (*m2).Matrix[i][j] = (mat).Matrix[baseRow+i][baseCol+j];
      printf("\t%.2f",(*m2).Matrix[i][j]);
    
    }
    printf("\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: yeah so I did add that bit to the `matrixDeterminant` but still the matrix behaves as though uninitialised, that is, it does not store any values from the for loop which is being used to assign values to it.

Comment: @PranavTyagi I figured out what was wrong, answer is updated.

Comment: thanks a lot this makes a lot more sense!

Answer (score 0):

The `rows` and `cols` of `m2` are not set in `matrixDeterminant`, leaving them undefined. Then, when `DisplayMatrix` attempts to display the matrix, no values are are displayed (if the value of `rows` and `cols` is 0, but that is not necessarily always true).

This can be fixed by assigning `m2` with the correct dimensions in `matrixDeterminant`:

```
m2->rows = 2;
m2->cols = 2;
```

Comment: Did exactly that, and does work to an extent, it displays the `m2` however it has incorrect values, which are not the values which are assigned to it in the for loop.